# How do I get the name of a selected file in android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor

I am building a mobile app with `meteor`. Somewhere in my template I have the following code for reading the filenames, filesize and extension

```
const media_file = event.target.files[0]
const filename = media_file.name
const fsize = media_file.size
const filetype = media_file.type
const extension = filename.slice(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)
```

This works fine on a browser. But on mobile, the filename and extension reports a number. How do I get the proper filename and extention?

Comment: I think there is a Cordova plugin for this https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Comment: Thanks. The library is marked as deprecated.